# MS Access multiple item search from combo box

Tags: ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

[image: This is first combo box]
[image: This is second combo box]
I want to select multiple fields from each of combo box, like dubai and sharjah at same time. How to do it in MS Access.

Answer (score 0):

Change the combobox to a *listbox* and set properties to allow multiselect.